# Update Shinygooglevis chart without full reload

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis, shiny-server

Is it possible to change the data of a googlevis chart (any of them!) without forcing a full reload of the page/chart?

Current code that gives a very undesirable flicker when the map is being reloaded:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        print("Reloading..")
        invalidateLater(update_freq*1000, session)
        data <- loadDataFiles()
        output$gvis <- renderGvis(mapPlot(data)) //mapPlot returns a new gvisGeoChart
  })
```

Ideally I'd just reload my markers, not the chart itself.

Answer (score 3):

The googleVis Shiny bindings need to be rewritten to fix this problem. In the meantime I have prototyped some ideas [here](https://github.com/jcheng5/googleCharts) that you might want to check out; you can install it using `devtools::install_github("jcheng5/googleCharts")` and see the example [here](https://github.com/jcheng5/googleCharts/tree/master/inst/examples/test). It is pretty rough but you won't get the flickering and instability that currently occurs with googleVis + shiny.

Comment: Thanks Joe, basically the conclusion I reached yesterday.. Ended up going for your leaflet bindings instead, I suppose you support that?